# parameter '@id', which was not supplied when insert data into database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to insert the data based on the id and I have added the id in parameter but the error still show that id was not supplied.

```
public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string sql, CommandType type, params SqlParameter[] param)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        PrepareCommand(sql, conn, cmd, type, param);
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   // Error here (unhandled exception)
    }
}
```

Insert data function

```
public int AddUsers(Users user)
{
    int rel = 0;
    string sql = "INSERT INTO Student 
                  VALUES (@id, @groupId, @userInfo, @imagePath)";

    SqlParameter[] param = {
         new SqlParameter("@id", user.uid),
         new SqlParameter("@groupId", user.groupId),
         new SqlParameter("@userInfo",user.userInfo),
         new SqlParameter("@imagePath",user.imagePath),
    };

    rel = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(sql, CommandType.Text, param);

    return rel;
}
```

I will be calling the method if id is not null like example.

```
 if(id != 0)
 {
    int rel = AddUsers(user);
 }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include the full stacktrace of the exception? It might help

Comment: You are setting the command type to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` but executing an insert statement. You need `CommandType.Text` for this task.

Comment: You say that you are not calling the AddUser method if Id is not null, but your code checks for not 0, which is not equivalent to NULL. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for `id != 0` but use `user.uid` as parameter for `@id`. What type is `user.uid`? And be sure it's `!= null` because if you add `null`  as parameter-value, it's treated as not provided. If you need to insert NULL into the database use `DbNull.Value`